# mysql slow query on indexed column

Tags: mysql

Running a simple query on an indexed column, yet it's taking over 500ms.  These queries run often so it's affecting performance in a big way.

Just under 1M rows in the table, a very simple table.  Using MyISAM.  I don't understand why it's examining all rows, seems like it's ignoring the index!  I tried adding a second index on the field, a normal one instead of a unique index, didn't make any difference.  Thanks for looking.

```
# Time: 130730 22:00:07
# User@Host: engine[engine] @ engine [10.0.0.6]
# Query_time: 0.511209  Lock_time: 0.000050 Rows_sent: 1  Rows_examined: 932048
SET timestamp=1375236007;
SELECT * FROM `marketplacesales`.`sales_order` WHERE `marketplace_orderid` = 823123693003;

+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field               | Type                  | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                  | mediumint(8) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| marketplace_id      | smallint(5) unsigned  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| marketplace_orderid | varchar(255)          | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| datetime            | datetime              | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| added               | datetime              | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| phone               | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email               | varchar(255)          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| company             | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| name                | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address1            | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| address2            | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| city                | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| state               | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| zip                 | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| country             | varchar(255)          | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+---------------------+-----------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM `marketplacesales`.`sales_order` WHERE `marketplace_orderid` = 823123693003;
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table       | type | possible_keys                             | key  | key_len | ref  | rows   | Extra       |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | sales_order | ALL  | marketplace_orderid,marketplace_orderid_2 | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 932053 | Using where |
+----+-------------+-------------+------+-------------------------------------------+------+---------+------+--------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: Please post an `EXPLAIN` query.  That will tell you what indexes MySQL is using (if any).

Comment: (to wit: `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM \`marketplacesales\`.\`sales_order\` WHERE \`marketplace_orderid\` = 823123693003`)

Comment: added to the question, too long to fit in a comment.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to use explain to see what is happening.  My guess is that the index is *not* being used.

The `where` clause is:

```
WHERE `marketplace_orderid` = 823123693003;
```

As explained [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/type-conversion.html), the conversion will take place as floating point numbers.  This requires a conversion on `marketplace_orderid`.

Either fix the field in the table so it is numeric.  Or, put the value in quotes in the `where` clause:

```
WHERE `marketplace_orderid` = '823123693003';
```

The problem with quotes is that the actual value might have leading zeros, which would cause the match to fail.

Comment: very interesting gordon, I didn't know that. That's totally critical actually!

Comment: Gordon, thanks so much.  Now I understand the problem.  You rock!

Comment: +1 Implicit data conversions strike once again. Compare ints to ints, and strings to strings, people!

Answer (score 0):

Try using:

```
SELECT * FROM `marketplacesales`.`sales_order` WHERE `marketplace_orderid LIKE '823123693003%'
```

That should force the use of the index.

Also, if possible, I would consider changing the field to bigint intead of varchar